# Ruby on Rails - Install execjs on Debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debian, execjs

I'm trying to install ruby on rails on debian... I installed everything.

I installed execjs, therubyracer and node.js, too.

Everytime i wanna create a new controller it says:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.0.2/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.2.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.2.1/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
    from /home/adattilo/test/testt/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `require'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I made a reboot after the installation of execjs, therubyracer and node.js...

Comment: Please add a copy of your Gemfile and give us details on how you have ruby/rails installed on your system. Are you using RVM ?

Answer (score 5):

For platforms for which there is binary version of therubyracer gem available, there are no dependencies other than ruby and rubygems. If there is not a binary version for your system, then you will need to compile it from source. To do this, you must have v8 > 3.11.8 installed somewhere on your system.

Try adding following to your Gemfile

```
gem 'therubyracer', '0.11.0beta5'
gem 'libv8', '~> 3.11.8'
```

Now, cd to your project and bundle install

```
$ cd <project>
$ bundle install
```

Comment: I was facing the same issue in rails '3.2.14', adding above two gems helped me in getting rid of the error. Thanks.